# Problema al guardar tipo de Dato BigSerial en NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, backend, nestjs, typeorm

Tengo un inconveniente que me ha surgido en un proyecto a nivel personal. Estoy trabajando el backend con NestJS y el frontend con VueJS.

Estoy tratando de almacenar el valor de la columna **id** como tipo **BigSerial.**

Mi entidad se ve así:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment', { type: 'bigint' })
  id: number;
```

Mi dto así:

```
@IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  readonly id: number;
```

Mi service se ve así:

```
async update(id: number, cambios: UpdateRegistroDto) {
    const registro = await this.findOne(id);
    const updatedRegistro = this.RegistroRepo.merge(
      registro,
      cambios,
    );
    return this.RegistroRepo.save(updatedRegistro);
  }
```

A la hora de guardar el registro en una vista en VueJS, puedo sin ningún problema crear y eliminar registros. El inconveniente está cuando deseo editar uno de ellos. Sucede que si edito un registro, siempre queda el anterior registro y se crea un nuevo registro con los datos que intenté modificar.

--- Edit

Buenas, he encontrado una solución temporal, que ya no me duplica el registro, he dejado mi dto así:

```
@IsOptional()
@ApiProperty()
readonly id: string;
```

Mi entity así:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment', { type: 'bigint' })
  id: string;
```

El service ha quedado igual. El único punto es que el **id** me lo está guardando como string. Intentaré revisarlo :) Gracias.

Comment: Hace falta ver cómo estás intentando actualizar el registro.

Comment: @MauricioContreras he colocado el service

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir la función merge que tienes en RegistroRepo? Puede que tenga que ver con tu problema